# Copy table from Word to Excel Preserving Cell Size

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a set of Word documents, each document contains a table set up for printing so it prints on one full A4 page. Now I need to copy those tables to Excel, but the copy operation doesn't preserve Word table cell size, so I need to manually adjust it to make the  table in excel fit one full page. Is there a way to copy a table from Word to Excel and preserve cell size?

I am using Office 2007.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer to that question is no.

To make your life marginally easier, though, you can, in Excel, select all the columns containing the table you pasted in and double click the border between them (ie, the border between the column letters in the column header) to autosize the columns to their contents.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible [with some limitations](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/2928-copy-paste-excel-word-problems.html).

An object such as an Excel workbook cannot span more a page break. If you need that kind of thing, you need to use a different paste format. getting the font sizes to match, though, is as simple as making sure the Excel object is scaled to 100% of the original size in both dimensions.

From what I know, if you paste an Excel range using 'paste link' and the HTML format, then click in the pasted table and choose Table Tools|Layout|Properties > Table > Options and set the left & right margins to 0, that will greatly assist getting the data to fit within the page margins. Mind you, if the data doesn't fit within the same page margins in Excel, you can't expect it to in Word. One thing to be aware of on this front is that Excel actually shortens the printed row heights. You can prove this by inserting a circle into an Excel worksheet, then printing the sheet. When you measure the printed circle, you'll find its height to be less than its width.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround I have found:

Screenshot the word table, paste into the sheet, drag the image borders to the desired size, then drag the excel columns of the pasted table to match.

You can adjust the font size(s) of the pasted table if required to achieve approximate row heights

(Then delete the image.)

You can fine-tune the print outcome using Page Layout Scale to Fit